# Why does the 2021 Mac have a lower Ghz processor than the 2017?

Tags: imac

When I look at the [2017 specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP760?locale=en_US) it seems the 2017 provides

```
3.4GHz
3.4GHz quad‑core Intel Core i5 (Turbo Boost up to 3.8GHz)
3.5GHz
3.5GHz quad‑core Intel Core i5 (Turbo Boost up to 4.1GHz)
Configurable to 4.2GHz quad-core Intel Core i7 (Turbo Boost up to 4.5GHz)
3.8GHz
3.8GHz quad‑core Intel Core i5 (Turbo Boost up to 4.2GHz)
Configurable to 4.2GHz quad-core Intel Core i7 (Turbo Boost up to 4.5GHz)
```

Where as the [2021 processor](https://www.apple.com/imac-27/specs/) starts at only 3.1Ghz and goes up to the same processing of 3.8Ghz:

```
3.1GHz
3.1GHz 6‑core 10th-generation Intel Core i5, Turbo Boost up to 4.5GHz
```

Comment: Probably to reduce power consumption, offset by better use of processing power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it you are concerned that in some way a lower GHz indicates less powerful CPU.  But let's look in a little detail at the GHz values and the different 'generation' of CPU.  I will just consider the lowest specs, that is

- 2017: 3.4GHz quad‑core Intel 7th-generation Core i5 (Turbo Boost up to 3.8GHz)
- 2021: 3.1GHz 6‑core Intel 10th-generation Core i5, Turbo Boost up to 4.5GHz.

Firstly there is 3-generations of Intel's Core processors between the two.  Without attempting to be specific, we can assume some improvement in efficiency for the same speed processor.

For mostly single-threaded applications (e.g. browser, word processor) the Turbo-boost value is important.  Here we see in increase in processor speed from 3.8 to 4.5 GHz.

The processor load will increase as more applications (and background tasks) are running and as the type of application moves to those being multi-threaded which can use many processor cores.  Such applications include photo and video processing.

At maximum load, all 4 cores (2017) or all 6 cores (2021) will become fully utilised.  When fully utilised the processor speed may reduce to 3.4 GHz (2017) and 3.1 GHz (2021). If we multiply cores by GHz (3.4x4 and 3.1x6) we can see that that the newer processor is capable of considerably more work - the lower speed is outweighed by the increase in core count.

In practice both CPUs will probably run a bit faster than 3.4 and 3.1 GHz when under full load unless the ambient temperature is high.

In summary we have three things making the newer CPU outperform the older one:

- Newer generation of processor;
- Single threaded speed (maximum Turbo Boost);
- Core count (even though base speed is lower).

You also might like to know that, as a power saving measure, both processors will reduce their speed when under a light load.

And, of course, there are considerably higher performance CPUs available for both 2017 and 2021 iMacs if that is desired.

Finally you might like to browse Geekbench results for the two processors:

- [2017](https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Intel%207500%20core%20i5)
- [2021](https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/search?q=intel%2010500%20core%20i5)

These show a modest improvement in single threaded performance and a greater improvement in multi threaded.

Comment: Shows there's still hope for the old girl yet - https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/7598260 2009 Mac Pro. Starting to struggle on the single core figures, but the multi-core still looking fine ;))